# Where exactly is Ashtavakra Gita found?

Tags: scripture, gita

I have been trying to find information on Ashtavakra gita but in vain.

Where is the text Ashtavakra Gita found? Is it part of any purana/itihasa? If so, which purana/itihasa and which canto and chapter?

Who is the first one to comment on this text? In which century?

Comment: It seems a separate book and not part of any itihasa-purana.

Comment: It is a dialogue between King Janak and Rishi Ashtaavkra and separate (not a part of any other bigger text).. It is also known as Ashtaavakra Mahaageetaa.

Answer (score 4):

According to [*The Cultural Heritage of India, Vol. II*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.284245/page/n231/mode/2up), the Aṣṭāvakra Gītā a.k.a Aṣṭāvakra Saṃhitā is an independent work. It doesn't belong to any known epic or Purāṇa.

> #### IMITATIONS OF THE BHAGAVAD-GĪTĀ AND LATER GĪTĀ LITERATURE
>
> EXTENT AND NATURE
>
> Besides the Bhagavad-Gītā, which is generally known as 'the Gītā',
> scholars have noticed many other tracts of varying lengths composed in
> verse form to which the title 'Gītā' is given. Sixteen of them are
> from (a) the Mahābhārata, twenty from (b) the Purāṇas and similar
> treatises, and **four (c) found as independent works untraced to any
> other known epic or Purāṇa**.
>
> Under the group marked (a) are to be found: Utathya-Gītā,
> Vāmadeva-Gītā, Ṛṣabha-Gītā, Ṣaḍaja-Gītā, Sampāka-Gītā, Maṅki-Gītā,
> Bodhya-Gītā, Vicakhnu-Gītā, Hārīta-Gītā, Vṛtra-Gītā, Parāśara-Gītā,
> Haṃsa-Gītā, Brahma-Gītā, Anu-Gītā and Brāhmaṇa-Gītā.
>
> In the group marked (b) are included: two Kapila-Gītās, Haṃsa-Gītā,
> Bhikṣu-Gītā, Devī-Gītā, Gaṇeśa-Gītā, two Brahma-Gītās, Sūta-Gītā,
> three Yama-Gītās, Śiva-Gītā, two Rāma-Gītās, Sūrya-Gītā and
> Vasiṣṭha-Gītā.
>
> **Under the group marked (c)** come four works: **Aṣṭāvakra-Gītā**,
> Avadhūta-Gītā, Uttara-Gītā, and Pāṇḍava-Gītā.
>
> The names Īśvara-Gītā, Haṃsa-Gītā and Vyāsa-Gītā in all probability
> refer to the Bhagavad-Gītā only and no other work.